# Standalone Mobile Application: RadPhp or Delphi IntraWeb

Tags: delphi, intraweb, tms, radphp

I am planning to write a application that will be used primarily by mobile device users (iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows and Nokia). The application will be a standalone application (i.e. not run from a server).

The app will from time to time need to get new rates from a server (FTP or HTTP).

In the future I might extend the service so that the users can login into a Web application so that they can access their records on a desktop and synchoronise on their mobile devices.

I have worked with Delphi and PHP but never with Delphi IntraWeb and RadPHP.

I understand for different interfaces I might need different UI settings. My main aim is to easily manage the software going forward especially when it will be supported on many mobile devices and desktop.

RadPHP supports PhoneGap and from what I see, I can use it for iPhone and Android only.
With IntraWeb, I recently came across "TMS IntraWeb iPhone Controls Pack", http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsiwiphone.asp which looks promising.

So which path would you recommend for me? IntraWeb with TMS or RadPHP with PhoneGap? Or am I totally missing something here?

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is really inappropriate for SO, as it's a discussion question and the answer is really not possible to provide. (It's whatever you would be most comfortable with, and what would best fit your individual needs, and no one here can determine that but you.) SO is designed for short, concise programming (code) related questions that can be answered specifically and that can have a single best answer chosen. You might want to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what types of questions are appropriate for the design here.

Comment: Thanks for that Ken, I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Worst Language Ever (PHP) or Worst Framework Ever (IntraWeb) on a great language (Delphi). What a choice.  PHP has lots of adherents, but it's a language that, if you removed all the accidental complexity, would no longer exist.  IntraWeb is suitable for demos, but not for production websites.  Given the choice, if they were the last two options in the world, I'd go with PHP, just because it actually works, while quirky. RadPHP is actually a pretty cool platform, and language-purist concerns aside, PHP is a sane practical choice. (Cough.)

Comment: For a real iPhone app, there's really no choice -- Just learn Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what you need to do exactly, but if all your app does is get some information from a server once and a while (I assume via HTTP), I wouldn't create an "app".

Just create a simple HTML file and use JavaScript to run your code.
That will make sure that it runs on every type of device, even for the coming 10 years or so.
You could make use of [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/) or [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) to give a bit of a slick look and feel. That's how I'd do it.

**Update Nov 2020 (Update 8 years later)**: advice to make it as much web based as possible still stands, but there are better JavaScript frameworks out there right now. ReactJS makes more sense today. Let's see what happens in the coming 8 years. I'll try to come back in 2028 to update this again :)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will have a look at SmartMobile Studio. With further research I found about Corona. Since it is native I am going to go with Corona and Lua.

Answer (score 1):

You made me confused. Why you need a standalone app that should be deployed and maintained for each different mobile device. Develop a SOA web site. Let the users login via web browser (whether they are on mobile or desktop) and do whatever... You can use RadPHP or any other tool (notepad :) ) to achive this. Maybe I misunderstood your scenario but you seem as confused as me.

NOTE: Don't even think about Intraweb.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I do not know about *IntraWeb*.

About **RadPHP**, I think it would fit your needs. It helps you develop your application “the RAD way”, specially the interface (with components based on jQuery Mobile), and you can develop it client-side, using only JavaScript code (no PHP).

Later, you can use *AJAX* (in RadPHP it is a matter of toggling a boolean property) to enable server-side scripting (PHP), and do whatever you like in devices with a network connection.

About RadPHP supporting only *Android* and *iPhone*: (1) the latest update also supports *Blackberry*, and (2) you can get RadPHP to generate a PhoneGap project for any of those three platforms, get the www folder, and use the [**PhoneGap Build service**](https://build.phonegap.com/) to get it build for any other mobile platform in the cloud.

Anyway, in the end is a matter of personal choice. Try both, and decide later!

Comment: Thanks for the comments Gallaecio, I started researching more on the PhoneGap and came across issues about the speed of the applications. I have decided to go with Corona with Lua. I will be using RadPHP for the website. It would be easier/cheaper to host a RadPHP application than a IntraWeb application.

Answer (score 0):

For Intraweb you may also consider Mobile Suite from CgDevTools.

http://www.cgdevtools.com

Comment: Thanks Hugo, we already has some TMS controls. So we will use them if possible in the future.